# How to properly dispose of SWT/JavaFX FXCanvas

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, swt

I have an SWT/JavaFX FXCanvas that uses a WebView as root (to its Scene) instance embedded into a custom Composite:

```
class MyComposite extends Composite {
   FXCanvas canvas = createFXCanvasWithWebView();

   dispose() {
      webView.load(null);
      canvas = null;
      super.dispose();
   }
}
```

Is this sufficient to clean up all used resources (especially loaded images in the used WebView instance)?

Answer (score 0):

`webView.getEngine().load(null);` is more than enough.

`canvas = null` is redundant.

Comment: When loading/closing (several times) a html page with images, the memory keeps growing (in the OS's task manager, using (Windows Process Explorer) . The profiler's (jvisualvm) monitor shows a constant usage of heap.